# Selecting Records in Joined Tables

Tags: sql, ms-access, join, left-join

I have two tables in MS Access. One an Appointment table and one a Slot table. Like so:
[image: Tables]

Now I would like to select every record from the slot table and if there is a record with TeacherID = "CR" in the appointment table I would like it to display the StudentID.

This is the SQL I have so far:

```
SELECT Slot.SlotNumber, Slot.SlotTime, Appointment.TeacherID
FROM Slot LEFT JOIN Appointment ON Slot.SlotNumber = Appointment.SlotNumber
WHERE Appointment.TeacherID="CR"
```

However this only selects the slots where there is a record in the Appointment table. Any suggestions? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you correct. You do not want the `where` statement. Instead put it in the `LEFT JOIN`. Like this:

```
SELECT 
  Slot.SlotNumber, 
  Slot.SlotTime, 
  Appointment.TeacherID
FROM 
  Slot 
  LEFT JOIN Appointment 
    ON (Slot.SlotNumber = Appointment.SlotNumber
    AND Appointment.TeacherID="CR")
```

Comment: I just tried that in Access. It's not liking it. It's throwing the error "Join Expression not supported". Is that because it's something MS-Access doesn't like?

Comment: I updated the answer. I read the Access do not like this kinda join if you do not have parentheses. Can you give it a try?